# Understanding rpart package - unexpected behavior when swaping two columns in explanatory varaibles table

Tags: rpart

I have a problem understanding the behavior of rpart function of R.

Here is the r code part :

```
library(rpart);

library(rpart.plot)

data(ptitanic); 

attr(ptitanic$age,"class") <- NULL;

class(ptitanic$age);

#This is a function which draws the tree 

arbre=function(data){

  set.seed(415)

   ptitanicTree  = rpart(survived~., data = data, 
                        control = rpart.control(minsplit = 5, cp = 0), 
                        method = "class")       


   ptitanicOptimal = prune(ptitanicTree, 
                           cp = ptitanicTree$cptable[which.min(ptitanicTree$cptable[,4]),1] )


   prp(ptitanicOptimal,extra=1)
}

data1=ptitanic[,c(1,2,3,4,5,6)];

arbre(data1)

# I change the position switching column 5 and 6
data2=ptitanic[,c(1,2,3,4,6,5)];

# Here i get an another tree : why ?
arbre(data2)
```

Is anyone able to explain why we get two different trees we have only changed the position of columns in data input ?

[image: First Tree]
[image: Second Tree]

Comment: You did not provide a reproducible example, there is no `ptitanic` data in base R, nor in `rpart` package. As about the results, they are nearly the same -- the only difference is that pruning returned one extra level.

Comment: @tim : thank's I have edited the post, the data frame is in the R package rpart.plot (also used to plot the trees). Best regards

Comment: By the way the parameter "cp" seems involved in this curious behavior but I can't explain how. regards

Comment: Please indent your code properly when asking others to read it.

Comment: You might get more responses if your change your title. Your title `Understanding rpart package` is too vague.  A better title would be something like `Why does rpart generate a different tree when the order of the variables in the data is changed?`.

Comment: @Stehpen Milborrow : I have detailed a bit more the question in the title, it should be ok now.

Comment: @Matthew Durry  : The identation looks mostly ok to me, if you feel like it please edit the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rpart algorithm can generate different trees when the order of the variables is changed because it's a [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm).  At each step when when growing the tree, it may so happen that the optimum Gini Impurity may be achieved by more than one potential split-variable -- which of those variables is actually selected by the algorithm will depend on the order in which the algorithm scans the variables.

Comment: Thanks for changing the title to be more informative for others who have the same question.